# Why does this algorithm work so much faster in python than in C++?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

I was reading "Algorithms in C++" by Robert Sedgewick and I was given this exercise: rewrite this weigted quick-union with path compression by halving algorithm in another programming language.

The algorithm is used to check if two objects are connected, for example for entry like 1 - 2, 2 - 3 and 1 - 3 first two entries create new connections whereas in the third entry 1 and 3 are already connected because 3 can be reached from 1: 1 - 2 - 3, so the third entry would not require creating a new connection.

Sorry if the algorithm description is not understandable, english is not my mother's tongue.

So here is the algorithm itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

static const int N {100000};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i; 
    int j; 

    int id[N];  
    int sz[N]; // Stores tree sizes

    int Ncount{}; // Counts the numbeer of new connections 
    int Mcount{}; // Counts the number of all attempted connections

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        id[i] = i;
        sz[i] = 1;
    }

    while (Ncount < N - 1)
    {
        i = rand() % N;
        j = rand() % N;

        for (; i != id[i]; i = id[i])
            id[i] = id[id[i]];

        for (; j != id[j]; j = id[j])
            id[j] = id[id[j]];

        Mcount++;

        if (i == j) // Checks if i and j are connected 
            continue;

        if (sz[i] < sz[j]) // Smaller tree will be 
                           // connected to a bigger one 
        {
            id[i] = j;
            sz[j] += sz[i];
        }
        else
        {
            id[j] = i;
            sz[i] += sz[j];
        }

        Ncount++;
    }

    cout << "Mcount: " << Mcount << endl;
    cout << "Ncount: " << Ncount << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know a tiny bit of python so I chose it for this exercise. This is what got:

```
import random

N = 100000

idList = list(range(0, N))
sz = [1] * N

Ncount = 0
Mcount = 0

while Ncount < N - 1:

    i = random.randrange(0, N)
    j = random.randrange(0, N)

    while i is not idList[i]:
        idList[i] = idList[idList[i]]
        i = idList[i]

    while j is not idList[j]:
        idList[j] = idList[idList[j]]
        j = idList[j]

    Mcount += 1

    if i is j:
        continue

    if sz[i] < sz[j]:
        idList[i] = j
        sz[j] += sz[i]
    else:
        idList[j] = i
        sz[i] += sz[j]

    Ncount += 1

print("Mcount: ", Mcount)
print("Ncount: ", Ncount)
```

But I stumbled upon this interesting nuance: when I set N to 100000 or more C++ version version appears to be a lot slower than the python one - it took about 10 seconds to complete the task for the algorithm in python whereas C++ version was doing it so slow I just had to shut it down.

So my question is: what is the cause of that? Does this happen because of the difference in rand() % N and random.randrange(0, N)? Or have I just done something wrong?

I'd be very grateful if someone could explain this to me, thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you compile your C++ code? Make sure to enable compiler optimizations, e.g. by compiling with `-O2` or `-O3` with gcc or clang. The performance of unoptimized C++ code in meaningless.

Comment: I compiled it in my QtCreator which uses VS2013 compiler I believe. Should I try to compile it on Linux?

Comment: If you use VS, make sure to choose a Release build, not a Debug build.

Comment: Does the python version give the right result?

Comment: I did that, it doesnt seem to make a difference :(


Yeah, I believe it does.

Comment: It runs fast for me. Perhaps your platform has a really bad RNG. Try using [the minimal PGC random function](http://www.pcg-random.org/download.html) instead. With `pcg32_random_t rng{0, 1337};` I get `Mcount: 515360`; `Ncount: 99999`.

Comment: Wow its really weird but I just tried the same code on Linux and it took less than a second D: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Those codes do different things.

You have to compare numbers in python with `==`.

```
>>> x=100000
>>> y=100000
>>> x is y
False
```

There might be other problems, haven't checked. Have you compared the results of the apps?

Comment: Thanks but it makes no difference in my case I believe.

Comment: @Goldutop: People *believe* in all kind of weird stuff. What you believe makes no difference.

Comment: `Ncount` will be incremented in every iteration as soon as you pass the threshold for interned integers.

Comment: Alright alright, but it doesn't change program's behavior.

Comment: It does, I get different results for `Mcount`. As long as the python code doesn't produce the same (and correct) result, your whole question is meaningless.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't. You probably forgot to seed the RNG. (That said, using `is` is crazy, and *probably* wrong.)

Comment: You might get different results because the program relies on random number generation, no?

Comment: By the way,  when I add code to print  Ncount on every iteration C++ gets very slow somewhere near 30000 mark whereas Python gets to 97000 very fast and gets a bit slower there.

I just want to know if my code in python is identical to C++ version since I have very little expirience with pyton ( I changed is to == and is not to != )

Comment: @Goldutop None of that matters. Your code is full of bugs, so fix those first and compare two working algorithms.

Comment: Yeah actually it worked perfectly fine on Linux, thanks for advice mate. What bugs are you talking about btw?

Comment: However if `x = 3` and `y=3` then `(x is y) is True` ;)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out above the codes are not equivalent and especially when it comes to the use of `is` vs `==`.

Look at the following Pyhton code:

```
while i is not idList[i]:
    idList[i] = idList[idList[i]]
    i = idList[i]
```

This is evaluated **0 or 1 times**. Why?. Because if the `while` evaluates to `True` the 1st time, then `i = idList[i]` makes the condition `True` in the 2nd pass, because now `i` is for sure a number which `is` in `idList`

The equivalent `c++`

```
for (; i != id[i]; i = id[i])
     id[i] = id[id[i]];
```

Here the code is checking against *equality* and not against **presence** and the number of times it runs it is not fixed to be *0 or 1*

So yes ... using `is` vs `==` makes a **huge** difference because in Python you are testing *instance equality* and *being contained in*, rather than testing simple *equality* in the sense of *equivalence*.

The comparison of Python and C++ above is like comparing apples and pears.

Note: The short answer to the question would be: *The Python version runs much faster because it is doing a lot less than the C++ version*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but  it seems I had a  problem with my compiler and not with my code because when I compiled C++ version with g++ it worked way faster than the python version.

Comment: Sorry but `i = idList[i]` doesn't imply that `i == idList[i]` (or that `i != id[i]` is false, because `i` has changed with the assignment and the value you draw from idList[] is a different one. It can be but it must not. Example: i = 5 and idList[5] is 3. The next check is 3 != idList[3] and we don't know what idList[3] contains. So yes, the C++ version can (and will) run many more times. The OP (by recompiling without debugging under Linux) has only proven that C++, in spite of the disadvantage, is much faster.

Comment: And when it comes to "is" and "presence" in Python is because he assigns the value from the list and then checks if the just assigned value "is" the value just assigned from the list -> effectively checking for presence. I may not be Guido but I know what "is" is doing in the context of the code above.

Comment: @mementum You're right about the first part, but I still don't believe you about `is`. `i != idList[i]` *implies* `i is not idList[i]` (except for really odd cases like `float("nan")`) so if the C++ code does another loop it implies so will the Python code.